# window.print() refreshes page in iframe when I click cancel

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a an iframe inside my website with the following jquery code in it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#print_button').click(function() {
        window.print();
    });

});
```

The problem: When I click the print button, the print dialog opens correctly. Printing works correctly as well. But when I click the cancel button in the print dialog it closes but it also refreshes content in the iframe.

How can I avoid this behaviour?

Comment: Does this occur in one specific browser, or across all of them?

Comment: It happens in Firefox. I haven't tested in IE yet.

Comment: Just tested in IE. It happens there, too.

Comment: Is `#print_button` an anchor tag?

Comment: No. It is an input type="submit".

Comment: That's the problem. You are submitting a form when the focus returns to the page. Try adding a `return false;` after `window.print();`.

Comment: That worked. Thanks. Write it down as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As stated in the above comments, a form is being submitted when the button `#print_button` is clicked. This would force the page to refresh.

To prevent this, add a return value of `false` to the `onclick` event. This would cancel the form submission.

```
window.print();
return false;
```